# Cant overwrite firebase screen_view parameters

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-analytics

I want to track screens manually. The documentation suggests the following solution:

[image]

[Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#dart)

But its seems i cant overwrite parameters which have a'firebase_' prefix. I get the following error:

```
E/FA      (22878): Name starts with reserved prefix. Type, name: event param, firebase_screen
E/FA      (22878): Name starts with reserved prefix. Type, name: event param, firebase_screen_class
```

How am i supposed to set these parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since screen view is a predefined event, you can do

```
await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logScreenView(
    screenName: screenName, 
    screenClass: screenClass
);
```

This list of available events can be found here

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_analytics/latest/firebase_analytics/FirebaseAnalytics-class.html